# scraping historical data using drop-down list

Tags: r

I try to scrape data from https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=reportsSearch.process. As you see, there is a drop-down menu to call historical data. However, the link is not associated with the date range. Hence, I am not able to create a rvest loop going to relevant date and scraping data. How can I get the historical drug approval data from this page under these circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url, e.g., for July 2019 appears to be "https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=reportsSearch.process&rptName=0&**reportSelectMonth**=7&**reportSelectYear**=2019" so you could create a loop for months and years, apply them to the reportSelectMonth and reportSelectYear portions of the url, and invoke read_html() on each of the dynamically created url?

If you want all of 2017 and 2018, for example, you could do:

```
library(rvest)
baseUrl <- "https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm?event=reportsSearch.process&rptName=0&"
for (year in 2017:2018) {
    for (month in 1:12) {
        url <- paste0(baseUrl, "&reportSelectMonth=", month, "&reportSelectYear=", year)
        p <- read_html(url)
        # do stuff
    } 
}
```